# List each file that doesn't match a pattern recursively

Tags: linux, grep

Tried the following command, it lists all the lines including file names
which are not matching the given pattern.

```
grep -nrv "^type.* = .*"
```

"But what we need is list of file names in a folder with content 
which does not have even a single occurrence of above pattern."

Your help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need the `-L` option:

```
grep -rL '^type.* = .*' directory_name
```

---

From the GNU `grep` manual:

**-L, - -files-without-match**
    Suppress normal output; instead print the name of each input file from which no output
    would normally have been printed. The scanning will stop on the first match.